# while деление целочисленных

Tags: python, python-3.x

даны целые числа a и b (a > b) Определить результат целочисленного деления a на b, не использую стандартную операцию целочисленного деления

Comment: Недавно был аналогичный вопрос про умножение. Вы из одного класса что ли? Многократное вычитание применяйте.

Comment: @user286104, Вы сами пробовали решать данную задачу? В какой именно части у Вас возникает вопрос? уточните, пожалуйста

Comment: a, b = 179, 37
while a > b:
    a = a - b
print(a) 

результат деления должен быть 4,8  если с помощью цикла многократно вычитать получается остаток от вычитания

Comment: должно ли решение работать с отрицательными числами?

Comment: про отрецательные условия ничего не сказано в условии

Comment: [целые числа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE) могут быть и положительными и отрицательными.

Answer (score 3):

Многократное вычитание в цикле - это скучно!

Воспользуйтесь логарифмами:

```
In [74]: import math

In [75]: def div(a,b):
    ...:     return int(math.e**(math.log(a) - math.log(b)))
    ...:

In [76]: div(15,5)
Out[76]: 3

In [77]: div(15,4)
Out[77]: 3

In [78]: div(15,6)
Out[78]: 2
```

PS это решение работает только для чисел больших единицы...

---

вот более надежная, но скучная версия:

```
def div(a,b):
    def sign(x):
        return 1 if x > 0 else -1 if x < 0 else 0
    if b == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')
    sgn = sign(a * b)
    a, b = max(abs(a), abs(b)), min(abs(a), abs(b))
    res = 0
    while True:
        a -= b
        res += 1
        if a < b:
            return sgn * res
```

Примеры:

```
In [36]: div(-20, 10)
Out[36]: -2

In [37]: div(-20, -10)
Out[37]: 2

In [38]: div(2, 1)
Out[38]: 2

In [39]: div(2, 0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-d4f2e18433d9> in <module>()
----> 1 div(2, 0)

<ipython-input-35-52cd9b708b90> in div(a, b)
      3                 return 1 if x > 0 else -1 if x < 0 else 0
      4         if b == 0:
----> 5                 raise ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')
      6         sgn = sign(a * b)
      7         a, b = max(abs(a), abs(b)), min(abs(a), abs(b))

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: это не работает, к примеру `div(0,1)`, `div(2, 1)`. Если мы выбираем реализации, которые только некоторых параметров работают, то можно проще написать: `div = lamba a, b: 42` (есть бесконечное число a, b параметров, для которых эта реализация правильное значение возвращает :)

Comment: @jfs, да, решение работает только для чисел больших единицы...

Comment: и для больше единицы тоже ломается.

Comment: @jfs, учитывая данное условие `(a > b)` ??

Comment: конечно. Подсказка: точность целых чисел в Питоне не ограничена

Comment: @jfs, в общем да, код сломается с `OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')` для очень больших чисел.

Comment: и код может молча неверный результат вернуть.

Comment: более "надёжный и скучный" вариант также неверен. Наверно, если правильный результат раз за разом не получается, то не такая уж и скучная задача :)

Answer (score 1):

В Питоне, `a // b` это `floor(a / b)` (математически).

Простой цикл работает для положительных чисел:

```
def unsigned_div(a, b):
    assert a >= 0 and b > 0, (a, b)
    q = 0
    while a >= b:
        a -= b
        q += 1
    return q
```

Чтобы тот же результат, что и `a//b` получить для всех целых чисел:

```
def div(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError
    elif a == 0:
        return 0
    elif a > 0 and b > 0:  # both positive
        return unsigned_div(a, b)
    elif a < 0 and b < 0:  # both negative
        return unsigned_div(-a, -b)
    else:  # different signs
        return -1 - unsigned_div(abs(a)-1, abs(b))
```

Последняя строчка связана с тем, что [округление в минус бесконечность в Питоне для целочисленного деления `a//b`](http://python-history.blogspot.ru/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html):

```
>>> 5 // 2
2
>>> 5 // -2
-3
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
def unsigned_div(a, b):
    assert a >= 0 and b > 0, (a, b)
    q = 0
    while a >= b:
        a -= b
        q += 1
    return q


def div(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError
    elif a == 0:
        return 0
    elif a > 0 and b > 0:  # both positive
        return unsigned_div(a, b)
    elif a < 0 and b < 0:  # both negative
        return unsigned_div(-a, -b)
    else:  # different signs
        return -1 - unsigned_div(abs(a)-1, abs(b))

# try your own input    
from browser import document, html
@document["mybutton"].bind("click")
def on_click(event):
    a = int(document['a'].value)
    b = int(document['b'].value)
    document <= html.P(f'{a} // {b} == {div(a,b)}')
</script><div><label for="a">a: <input id="a" value="5"></div><div><label for="b">b: <input id="b" value="-2"></div><button id="mybutton">div(a, b)</button></body>
```

Это работает, но медленно даже для умеренно больших чисел. Есть быстрее алгоритмы, к примеру, [long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Integer_division_(unsigned)_with_remainder):

```
def unsigned_div_long(a, b):
    assert a >= 0 and b > 0
    q, r = 0, 0  # quotient, remainder
    for i in reversed(range(a.bit_length())):
        r <<= 1
        # set the least-significant bit of r equal to bit i of the numerator
        r |= (a >> i) & 1
        if r >= b:
            r -= b
            q |= (1 << i)  # set i-th bit
    return q
```

Этот алгоритм реализует обычное [деление столбиком](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8,_%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8,_%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8,_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A0) (более простой вариант, использующий двоичную систему — только две цифры `0`, `1`): начинаем слева (старший бит в делимом `a`) и копируем биты в остаток `r` пока он не станет больше либо равен делителю `b`; вычитаем делитель `r -= b` и выставляем текущий бит в результате; повторяем пока биты делимого не закончатся. Можно [по шагам пройти, нажимая на <kbd>Forward></kbd>](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20unsigned_div_long%28a,%20b%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20assert%20a%20%3E%3D%200%20and%20b%20%3E%200%0A%20%20%20%20q,%20r%20%3D%200,%200%20%20%23%20quotient,%20remainder%0A%20%20%20%20for%20i%20in%20reversed%28range%28a.bit_length%28%29%29%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r%20%3C%3C%3D%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20set%20the%20least-significant%20bit%20of%20r%20equal%20to%20bit%20i%20of%20the%20numerator%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r%20%7C%3D%20%28a%20%3E%3E%20i%29%20%26%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20r%20%3E%3D%20b%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r%20-%3D%20b%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20q%20%7C%3D%20%281%20%3C%3C%20i%29%20%20%23%20set%20i-th%20bit%0A%20%20%20%20return%20q%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28bin%28unsigned_div_long%280b1100,%200b100%29%29%29%20%20%20%20&cumulative=false&curInstr=5&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

#### `12 // 4 == 0b1100 // 0b100 == 0b11 == 3`

[image: binary long division work]

Этот алгоритм требует операций пропорционально количеству битов в делимом, что гораздо лучше первого варианта, где количество операций пропорционально самому результату (частному):

```
>>> unsigned_div_long(2**53, 2)
4503599627370496
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
def unsigned_div_long(a, b):
    """
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Integer_division_(unsigned)_with_remainder
    """
    assert a >= 0 and b > 0
    q, r = 0, 0  # quotient, remainder
    for i in reversed(range(a.bit_length())):
        r <<= 1
        # set the least-significant bit of r equal to bit i of the numerator
        r |= (a >> i) & 1
        if r >= b:
            r -= b
            q |= (1 << i)  # set i-th bit
    return q
    
def div(a, b, unsigned_div=unsigned_div_long):
    if b == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError
    elif a == 0:
        return 0
    elif a > 0 and b > 0:  # both positive
        return unsigned_div(a, b)
    elif a < 0 and b < 0:  # both negative
        return unsigned_div(-a, -b)
    else:  # different signs
        return -1 - unsigned_div(abs(a)-1, abs(b))
    

# try your own input    
from browser import document, html
@document["mybutton"].bind("click")
def on_click(event):
    a = int(document['a'].value)
    b = int(document['b'].value)
    document <= html.P(f'{a} // {b} == {div(a,b)}')
</script><div><label for="a">a: <input id="a" value="9007199254740991"></div><div><label for="b">b: <input id="b" value="-2"></div><button id="mybutton">div_long(a, b)</button></body>
```

Для ещё больших чисел, можно [метод Ньютона использовать, чтобы найти обратное `1/b` и умножить на `a`, чтобы ответ получить](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Newton%E2%80%93Raphson_division). Вот реализация, использующая только целочисленную арифметику, на основе кода из вопроса [Newton-Raphson Division With Big Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27801397/4279):

```
def unsigned_div_newton(a, b):
    assert a >= 0 and b > 0
    if a <= b:
        return int(a == b)

    k = a.bit_length() + b.bit_length()  # a*b < 2**k
    x = 2  #  0 < x < 2**(k+1)/b  # initial guess for convergence
    lastx = None
    while lastx != x:
        lastx = x
        x = (x * (2**(k + 1) - x * b)) >> k
    if x*b < 2**k: 
        x += 1
    return (a * x) >> k
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/ZNR9Eo):

```
>>> unsigned_div_newton(2**1000, 2)
535754303593133660474212524530000905280702405852766803721875194185175525562468061246599189407847929063797336458776573412593572642846157021799228878734928740196728388741211549271053730253118557093897709107652323749179097063369938377958277197303853145728559823884327108383021491582631219341860283403468
```

Теоретически ошибка квадратично уменьшается на каждой итерации (быстрая сходимость). Приведённая реализация фактически медленнее реализации на основе «деления столбиком»:

```
$ pypy -mperf timeit -s 'from test_integer_division import unsigned_div_newton as div' 'div(2**1000, 2)'
.........
Mean +- std dev: 719 us +- 14 us
$ pypy -mperf timeit -s 'from test_integer_division import unsigned_div_long as div' 'div(2**1000, 2)'                                                                        
.........
Mean +- std dev: 133 us +- 4 us
```

Comment: преподаватель задавший задание наверное будет в легком шоке...

Comment: @MaxU: это уже не однократно обсуждали: происхождение вопроса значение не имеет, ответы на Stack Oveflow не только для автора вопроса существуют. [Какими должны быть критерии оценки качества базы знаний?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант

```
import math

lst1 = [20, 35, 47, 80, 93, 99]
lst2 = [9.8, 6.1, 3.6, 7.01, 9.43, 66]

for i in range(6):
    print(math.floor(lst1[i] / lst2[i]))
    # print(math.floor(lst1[i] / lst2[i]) == lst1[i] // lst2[i]) True
```

Но если нужно именно так решать задачу, я не понимаю в чём появилась проблема

```
lst1 = [20, 35, 47, 80, 93, 99]
lst2 = [9.8, 6.1, 3.6, 7.01, 9.43, 66]

for i in range(6):
    a = lst1[i]
    b = lst2[i]
    result = 0

    while a >= b:
        a -= b
        result += 1

    print(result)
```

Comment: нужно без import math

Comment: это не работает для `a=5; b=-2`